# Running npm audit gives unexpected audit report format

Tags: npm, npm-audit

I have been reading the [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities) regarding `npm audit`.

It is supposed to return something like this:

[image]

But instead it returns this:

[image]

Why am I getting a different format?

All the docs and tutorials online do not show what I am seeing, which makes it difficult to follow along.

I have tried it on 3 different terminals; the Mac Terminal, iTerm, and the terminal inside Visual Studio Code. All show the same thing.

Also checked the npm version and it's up to date (8.0.0).

Comment: Same for me ‍♀️